# bilinear interpolation using java

Tags: java, image

I am trying to zoom an image twice using bilinear interpolation, but it's not working.It is giving errors like division by 0 , out of range value(the output color has exceeded 255). Here is my code :

```
    int red1,green1,blue1;
    int red2,green2,blue2;
    int red3,green3,blue3;
    int red4,green4,blue4;
    int redf,greenf,bluef;
    int x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y;
    int a,b,c,d;
    int var[][]=new int[4][4];
    int inv[][]=new int[4][4];
    //int cons[][]=new int[1][4];
    //int col[][]=new int[1][4];
 for(int i=0;i<height*2;i++)
    {
        //l=0;
        for(int j=0;j<width*2;j++)
        {
            Color color=new Color(img.getRGB((int)(j/2),(int)(i/2)));
            red=color.getRed();
            green=color.getGreen();
            blue=color.getBlue();
            x=(int)(j/2);
            y=(int)(i/2);
            x1=(int)(j/2)+1;
            y1=(int)(i/2)+1;
            x2=(int)(j/2)-1;
            y2=(int)(i/2)-1;
            if(x1<0 || x1>=width || y1<0 || y1>=height)
            {
                //System.out.println("Yes");
                red1=0;
                green1=0;
                blue1=0;
            }
            else
            {
            Color c1=new Color(img.getRGB(x1,y1));
            red1=c1.getRed();
            green1=c1.getGreen();
            blue1=c1.getBlue();
            }
            if(x2<0 || x2>=width || y2<0 || y2>=height)
            {
                //System.out.println("Yes2");
                red2=0;
                green2=0;
                blue2=0;
            }
            else
            {
            Color c2=new Color(img.getRGB(x2,y2));
            red2=c2.getRed();
            green2=c2.getGreen();
            blue2=c2.getBlue();
            }
            if(x1<0 || x1>=width || y2<0 || y2>=height)
            {
                red3=0;
                green3=0;
                blue3=0;
            }
            else
            {
            Color c3=new Color(img.getRGB(x1,y2));
            red3=c3.getRed();
            green3=c3.getGreen();
            blue3=c3.getBlue();
            }
            if(x2<0 || x2>=width || y1<0 || y1>=height)
            {
                red4=0;
                green4=0;
                blue4=0;
            }
            else
            {
            Color c4=new Color(img.getRGB(x2,y1));
            red4=c4.getRed();
            green4=c4.getGreen();
            blue4=c4.getBlue();
            }
            if(x1<=0 || x1>width)
                x1=0;
            if(x2<=0 || x2>width)
                x2=0;
             if(y1<=0 || y1>height)
                y1=0;
            if(y2<=0 || y2>height)
                y2=0;
            var[0][0]=x1;
            var[0][1]=y1;
            var[0][2]=x1*y1;
            var[0][3]=1;
            var[1][0]=x2;
            var[1][1]=y2;
            var[1][2]=x2*y2;
            var[1][3]=1;
            var[2][0]=x1;
            var[2][1]=y2;
            var[2][2]=x1*y2;
            var[2][3]=1;
            var[3][0]=x2;
            var[3][1]=y1;
            var[3][2]=x2*y1;
            var[3][3]=1;
            inv=invert(var);
            a=inv[0][0]*red1+inv[0][1]*red2+inv[0][2]*red3+inv[0][3]*red4;
            b=inv[1][0]*red1+inv[1][1]*red2+inv[1][2]*red3+inv[1][3]*red4;
            c=inv[2][0]*red1+inv[2][1]*red2+inv[2][2]*red3+inv[2][3]*red4;
            d=inv[3][0]*red1+inv[3][1]*red2+inv[3][2]*red3+inv[3][3]*red4;
            redf=a*x+b*y+c*x*y+d;
            a=inv[0][0]*green1+inv[0][1]*green2+inv[0][2]*green3+inv[0][3]*green4;
            b=inv[1][0]*green1+inv[1][1]*green2+inv[1][2]*green3+inv[1][3]*green4;
            c=inv[2][0]*green1+inv[2][1]*green2+inv[2][2]*green3+inv[2][3]*green4;
            d=inv[3][0]*green1+inv[3][1]*green2+inv[3][2]*green3+inv[3][3]*green4;
            greenf=a*x+b*y+c*x*y+d;
            a=inv[0][0]*blue1+inv[0][1]*blue2+inv[0][2]*blue3+inv[0][3]*blue4;
            b=inv[1][0]*blue1+inv[1][1]*blue2+inv[1][2]*blue3+inv[1][3]*blue4;
            c=inv[2][0]*blue1+inv[2][1]*blue2+inv[2][2]*blue3+inv[2][3]*blue4;
            d=inv[3][0]*blue1+inv[3][1]*blue2+inv[3][2]*blue3+inv[3][3]*blue4;
            bluef=a*x+b*y+c*x*y+d;

            System.out.println(redf+" "+greenf+" "+bluef);//prints the value
             Color nc=new Color(redf,greenf,bluef);
             img1.setRGB(j, i, nc.getRGB());


        }

    }
```

Kindly help . I am trying to zoom by 2 , and using 4 neighbours(bilinear approach)

Comment: The code is very complicated. If you have a constant factor of 2 you can simplify the code a lot. Just create averaged pixels between the ones you have. If you actually need to support arbitrary ones, you can still just see where the pixels fall between the existing ones and there will be no need for complicated matrices.

Comment: I have to implement the process of bilinear interpolation. It's a part of my assignment!! hence required

Comment: Bilinear interpolation still doesn't need to be this complicated. What did you learn while debugging about where the problems occur?

Comment: See i am trying for a constant factor here. But I have to generalize the code. I have explained my problem. Output values are exceeding the permissible color values

Comment: Most people will not run your code and try to find out where the errors happen, especially since it depends on the input data. It would help to show the actual exceptions, on what line they happen, what's the actual input data, what the algorithm is etc. Also it's your choice it you don't want to implement the algorithm in a simpler way which would reduce the possibilities of errors and make it a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being a bit late but for Bilinear Interpolation what you need to do is interpolation the results of two different interpolations. Basically it would look something like:

```
newX = x - 0.5
a1   = newX - (int) (newX)
newY = y - 0.5
a2   = newY - (int) (newY)

Red1 = getRed((int) (x - 0.5), (int) (y - 0.5))
Red2 = getRed((int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y - 0.5))
Red3 = getRed((int) (x - 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5))
Red4 = getRed((int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5))

newRed = lerp(lerp(Red1, Red2, a1), lerp(Red3, Red4, a1), a2)
```

This could, of course be repeated for green and blue.
X and Y in this are source coords, so if you wanted to find the color at (3, 5) of your new image you would run this on (1.5, 2.5) aka your original coords divided by your scaling factor (2).

In case you don't know lerp() is generaly just

```
lerp(x, y, a) 
    return x * (1 - a) + y * a;
```

but if cycles really matter to you or you have a primitive FPU or any number of other special case the less precise

```
return a + f * (b - a);
```

can work.

*

Edit:
Since we're in java I've just used
`(int)`
to signify rounding down but it doesn't actually have to be an int there.